# Can't access exfat partitions in windows linux bash

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to access an exfat partition by windows 10 linux bash, but the partition doesn't show in the /mnt/ path. Only the NTFS partitions.

Already tried to install the libs exfat-fuse exfat-utils. Nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported. The issue is being tracked on Microsoft's github bug tracker here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/801 (currently unassigned and not committed to as of 25/08/2016)

NOTE: As of 27/07/2017 the issue linked above has been resolved and FAT (and exFAT) partitions should be mountable.

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not supported yet...wait for full version, or you can write question to Microsoft developers